# Auto-Insert double quotes for HTML attributes broken

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

In VS2008, it used to be that whenever I was typing an html attribute in an .aspx page when I hit '=' a pair of double quotes was automatically inserted and the cursor placed inside them.  I guess I've changed a setting, but I don't know what to change to get that functionality back.

I am using Resharper if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In VS2008. Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Format -> Click "Insert attribute value quotes when typing".

Not sure how this is impacted with Resharper.

Comment: That works, I don't think Resharper gets involved with this setting.